# Issue in creating stack bar chart in python using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wanna try create location wise stacked bar chart I used following code

```
example of data 
 values are based on different different altitude on particular location  
location   N  T  S  Su
   1       25 20 30 40
   :
   :
   N
```

code:=

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  


N=np.array([20, 35, 30, 35, 27])
T=np.array([25, 32, 34, 20, 25])
S=np.array([30,5,35,10,20])
Su=np.array([30,5,35,10,20])


No =len(N)

ind = np.arange(No)    # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

p1 = plt.bar(ind, N,   width, color='r')
p2 = plt.bar(ind, T, width, color='y',bottom=N)
p3=plt.bar(ind,S,width,color='g',bottom=N+T)
p4=plt.bar(ind,Su,width,color='w',bottom=N+T+S)

plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('Scores by group and gender')
plt.xticks(ind+width/2., ('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5') )
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,200,10))
plt.legend( (p1[0], p2[0],p3[0],p4[0]), 

('Normal','Trapping','Super','Sub') )

plt.show()
```

It work on only for single value of T,N,S,Su
but some time on particular lat,long value for T,N,Su,S will repeat that should be adjust in stack bar but I unable to do it please help me
 value of T,N,S,Su grouped respectively have same colour based on grouped on single stack bar or all

```
example location  T    N    S     Su  N   T  S  N
            1     25   30  35     40  45  50 55 60
            :
            :
            N
```

In this example  N ,S has multiple value for single location on different altitude similarly there are N number of location and have similar condition please help me and give the solution

Comment: Could you provide "bad" input data (T, N, S, Su) in your code? Are you expecting length of bar for this non-scalar value [30, 45] to be max([30, 45]) or sum([30, 45]) or ...?

Comment: I edit My question please check the example at last

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `pandas` module:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Location':['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'],
                   'Normal':np.array([20, 35, 30, 35, 27]),
                   'Trapping':np.array([25, 32, 34, 20, 25]),
                   'Super':np.array([30,5,35,10,20]),
                   'Sub':np.array([30,5,35,10,20])})

df.plot(kind='bar', x='Location', stacked=True)
df2 = pd.concat([df, df[['Normal', 'Sub', 'Super']]], axis=1)

df2 = df2.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
df2.plot(kind='bar', x='Location', stacked=True)
```

For your example this produces:

[image]

If we duplicate some columns `pd.concat([df, df[['Normal', 'Sub', 'Super']]], axis=1)` to make:

```
    Location    Normal  Sub Super   Trapping    Normal  Sub Super
0   G1  20  30  30  25  20  30  30
1   G2  35  5   5   32  35  5   5
2   G3  30  35  35  34  30  35  35
3   G4  35  10  10  20  35  10  10
4   G5  27  20  20  25  27  20  20
```

Then you can group and sum, then plot again:

[image]